# Trying to interpret ASP.Net Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I put my code like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<%
    using System.Data.SqlClient
        public Static Main {
connection = new SqlConnection();

connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost:8080;Initial Catalog=dbo.Table1;";
connection.Open();

dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from customers", connection);
        }
%>

    <h2>This is a test for a database connection</h2> <%Response.Write(dataadapter) %>

</asp:Content>
```

And I got the following error message:

```
Source Error:

Line 6:  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
Line 7:  
Line 8:  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
Line 9:  {
Line 10:     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The only thing I can get out of it is that I might have put in some code incorrectly? This error is very opaque to me.

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Is there an error message?  Or does it really just say `Source Error`?

Comment: You're not actually showing the exception you're getting, only a partial stack trace. What error are you getting? My bet is that it's your connection string. You're missing what type of authentication you want - either by specifying the user name and password, or using a trusted connection, etc. Also, you can't really Reposone.Write a dataadapter object. I wouldn't expect to see actual data in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The following line doesn't really make sense:

```
public Static Main
```

Is this a class? An Interface?

Even if you change it to a static class, you are using variables without declaring them, and trying to execute code outside of any method body.

What exactly do you want that block of code to do?

Answer (score 1):

Take your code out of the page for testing the connection and place it in the Page_Load Event on within the code behind file.

Stay away from the inline code within a page until you completely understand it.

Try something like this

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <asp:label id = "lblLabel" runat="server"/>

</asp:Content>
```

in your code behind aka" the defaul.aspx.cs file try the following

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Default: System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection();

        connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost:8080;Initial Catalog=dbo.Table1;";
connection.Open();

         dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from customers", connection);

         lblLabel.Text = //something

     }
}
```

The Page_Load method is run every time the page is posted back to the server and is reloaded into the browser. It functions similar to a Main() method in a Winforms or Console application. The code behind (.cs) file usually contains most of your functionality while your .aspx file contains your design. It can contain logic but it becomes a whole new different animal when you mix both worlds. Before you become familiar with mixing styles understand the basics first.

What I coded was just a sample. For a more in depth description of the sqlDataAdapter take a look at this article on MSDN.

[sqlDataAdapter Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx)